# Optix / OIDN De-noiser functionality in Command line renders

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

In short I can't find any information on this, but does blender command line rendering support OIDN and Optix denoisers?

Our renders denoise through the renders on local machines (not in command line), but once they come out of the command line renderer there is no denoising when using either. It seems to do everything else in the compositor minus the denoising node.

Server is running Linux, blender 2.9, using 8 Tesla K80's. All documentation says this should function, is there anything special needed to trigger the denoising passes?

Comment: Bump for any possible help!